# Retrieving server name and database from connection string for crystal report asp.net web.config

Tags: asp.net

I am retrieving connection string based on value stored in cookie. Now
I am making crystal report. I cannot hard code server credential. I have to get these credential from connection string from web.config. so that I can pass these credentials to my crystal report.

```
ConnectionInfo reportConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
reportConnectionInfo.ServerName = connection string server name from web.config
reportConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = connection string database name from web.config
reportConnectionInfo.UserID = ...;
reportConnectionInfo.Password = ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
ConnectionInfo reportConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
reportConnectionInfo.ServerName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"];
reportConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseName"];
reportConnectionInfo.UserID = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserID"];
reportConnectionInfo.Password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
```

You can also provide the connection string as is in the web.config

```
string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"];
```

Comment: There are multiple connection string in web.config which i am retrieving based on cookie value.

Comment: Each connection string has a different name I guess? So use the name to retrieve the right one.